# GET Call for Getting List of Google Image Picture URLs

Tags: javascript, rest, api, google-custom-search, google-image-search

How would I get a JSON response of images that Google Images returns?

I have tried poking around in the documentation and found out that the Google Images API has been deprecated in favor for Google Custom Search API. From my understanding, Google Custom Search allows you to search within a domain instead of the entire web. I have tried making the following call but I was returned a JSON response without any image URLS

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={API_KEY}&cx={ENGINE_API}&q=vancouver&searchType=image

{
 "kind": "customsearch#search",
 "url": {
  "type": "application/json",
  "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json"
 },
 "queries": {
  "request": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - vancouver",
    "totalResults": "14400000",
    "searchTerms": "vancouver",
    "count": 10,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "004087055820537748846:jsb6pxcwlfc",
    "searchType": "image"
   }
  ],
  "nextPage": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - vancouver",
    "totalResults": "14400000",
    "searchTerms": "vancouver",
    "count": 10,
    "startIndex": 11,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "004087055820537748846:jsb6pxcwlfc",
    "searchType": "image"
   }
  ]
 },
 "context": {
  "title": "Google"
 },
 "searchInformation": {
  "searchTime": 0.387643,
  "formattedSearchTime": "0.39",
  "totalResults": "14400000",
  "formattedTotalResults": "14,400,000"
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Gastown in Vancouver",
   "htmlTitle": "Gastown in \u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e",
   "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=1cjm_9rHpykRpj_ynUSKktJuaVPo&hl=en",
   "displayLink": "www.google.com",
   "snippet": "Gastown in Vancouver",
   "htmlSnippet": "Gastown in \u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e",
   "mime": "image/",
   "image": {
    "contextLink": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=1cjm_9rHpykRpj_ynUSKktJuaVPo&hl=en",
    "height": 520,
    "width": 504,
    "byteSize": 65000,
    "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTM1MMx7p1iq8mIIAGQ9vhOq3jCO5DfD2Hg0JxDIP-xv_te-5y3bJ6aU3Ef",
    "thumbnailHeight": 131,
    "thumbnailWidth": 127
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Ramada Limited Vancouver Downtown",
   "htmlTitle": "Ramada Limited \u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e Downtown",
   "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=1B41Gt1WF8xLcJyfvc38rj8LBKgA&hl=en",
   "displayLink": "www.google.com",
   "snippet": "Ramada Limited Vancouver Downtown",
   "htmlSnippet": "Ramada Limited \u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e Downtown",
   "mime": "image/",
   "image": {
    "contextLink": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=1B41Gt1WF8xLcJyfvc38rj8LBKgA&hl=en",
    "height": 520,
    "width": 504,
    "byteSize": 71067,
    "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT_R6h1Kx-ClxwwdjQ96P31JIdEfg_MgFnTA82X3l9T_YwnBHe3NZ30Pd4g",
    "thumbnailHeight": 131,
    "thumbnailWidth": 127
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Vancouver Bike Route Stanley Park Seawall",
   "htmlTitle": "\u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e Bike Route Stanley Park Seawall",
   "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=14dxTKK_5KAhFsRhgdfVm9IBUSFo&hl=en_US",
   "displayLink": "www.google.com",
   "snippet": "Vancouver Bike Route Stanley Park Seawall",
   "htmlSnippet": "\u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e Bike Route Stanley Park Seawall",
   "mime": "image/",
   "image": {
    "contextLink": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=14dxTKK_5KAhFsRhgdfVm9IBUSFo&hl=en_US",
    "height": 520,
    "width": 504,
    "byteSize": 56235,
    "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSXPIwRIMWTkV2awxaXIGDSL0asRPMSGm3LTMPlChkGvfJywWuDY_YwP53F",
    "thumbnailHeight": 131,
    "thumbnailWidth": 127
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Gowalla Walking Tour of Vancouver",
   "htmlTitle": "Gowalla Walking Tour of \u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e",
   "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=18ob0bMMVH84t36U1_A3_jFbcx58&hl=en",
   "displayLink": "www.google.com",
   "snippet": "Gowalla Walking Tour of Vancouver",
   "htmlSnippet": "Gowalla Walking Tour of \u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e",
   "mime": "image/",
   "image": {
    "contextLink": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=18ob0bMMVH84t36U1_A3_jFbcx58&hl=en",
    "height": 520,
    "width": 504,
    "byteSize": 54143,
    "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmVpAm7SR0tSWPVMibBl3W6yEvYtnup8zn9ccWVvPZNRPF8w9EGM1unBGg",
    "thumbnailHeight": 131,
    "thumbnailWidth": 127
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "VANCOUVER MURAL FESTIVAL MURAL MAP",
   "htmlTitle": "\u003cb\u003eVANCOUVER\u003c/b\u003e MURAL FESTIVAL MURAL MAP",
   "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=1ur3X4PbXsGyg0aKhNNwEq03itN0&hl=en_US",
   "displayLink": "www.google.com",
   "snippet": "VANCOUVER MURAL FESTIVAL MURAL MAP",
   "htmlSnippet": "\u003cb\u003eVANCOUVER\u003c/b\u003e MURAL FESTIVAL MURAL MAP",
   "mime": "image/",
   "image": {
    "contextLink": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=1ur3X4PbXsGyg0aKhNNwEq03itN0&hl=en_US",
    "height": 520,
    "width": 504,
    "byteSize": 129311,
    "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR6DGPUW2U6pDAUmuVz_DR7cxU-LPUdMrOzbN2E0GHE8_FegyyHhvdOSX4V",
    "thumbnailHeight": 131,
    "thumbnailWidth": 127
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Best Western Hotel Downtown Vancouver",
   "htmlTitle": "Best Western Hotel Downtown \u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e",
   "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=1p-nRfVmGJpViUr4zPovQcaSTdeE&hl=en_US",
   "displayLink": "www.google.com",
   "snippet": "Best Western Hotel Downtown Vancouver",
   "htmlSnippet": "Best Western Hotel Downtown \u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e",
   "mime": "image/",
   "image": {
    "contextLink": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=1p-nRfVmGJpViUr4zPovQcaSTdeE&hl=en_US",
    "height": 520,
    "width": 504,
    "byteSize": 53972,
    "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhQD8cRDrRL2bPYEycxl55FqUCco8vCYkq1pfx4JYXHWXRe_s9Ttzy7Xc",
    "thumbnailHeight": 131,
    "thumbnailWidth": 127
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Carmana Plaza Hotel Vancouver",
   "htmlTitle": "Carmana Plaza Hotel \u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e",
   "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=1qf-nG5qQI0beJIftB7jWRSfIcHw&hl=en",
   "displayLink": "www.google.com",
   "snippet": "Carmana Plaza Hotel Vancouver",
   "htmlSnippet": "Carmana Plaza Hotel \u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e",
   "mime": "image/",
   "image": {
    "contextLink": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=1qf-nG5qQI0beJIftB7jWRSfIcHw&hl=en",
    "height": 520,
    "width": 504,
    "byteSize": 56307,
    "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEJBHFdUcUqMOLmHXj1acSwI0GLNniL8poTF9xKiIJUFV3US8vDUesTWc",
    "thumbnailHeight": 131,
    "thumbnailWidth": 127
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Seismic building risk in Vancouver",
   "htmlTitle": "Seismic building risk in \u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e",
   "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=1AzDOrFqjnR5qKqAkBnbqGDlbc_8&hl=en_US",
   "displayLink": "www.google.com",
   "snippet": "Seismic building risk in Vancouver",
   "htmlSnippet": "Seismic building risk in \u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e",
   "mime": "image/",
   "image": {
    "contextLink": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=1AzDOrFqjnR5qKqAkBnbqGDlbc_8&hl=en_US",
    "height": 520,
    "width": 504,
    "byteSize": 62217,
    "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvOomFOVNoIc6fVOBhyS9HXh3S5KkbxbvJw2EtkKjlNoVGF0Y7wlU8F9kC",
    "thumbnailHeight": 131,
    "thumbnailWidth": 127
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "1607- 1420 W. Georgia St, Vancouver",
   "htmlTitle": "1607- 1420 W. Georgia St, \u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e",
   "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=1b4WGaMzNOARvuejyduraaT-9Nhg&hl=en",
   "displayLink": "www.google.com",
   "snippet": "1607- 1420 W. Georgia St, Vancouver",
   "htmlSnippet": "1607- 1420 W. Georgia St, \u003cb\u003eVancouver\u003c/b\u003e",
   "mime": "image/",
   "image": {
    "contextLink": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=1b4WGaMzNOARvuejyduraaT-9Nhg&hl=en",
    "height": 520,
    "width": 504,
    "byteSize": 59096,
    "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQaKK52bEj0-tvFOOJw3kbqZoChXiWeQ9-wLoccNHNHQpOqaKwNSEk4wvM",
    "thumbnailHeight": 131,
    "thumbnailWidth": 127
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Correctional Centres in British Columbia",
   "htmlTitle": "Correctional Centres in British Columbia",
   "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=1Xiubw4z5fACCpd5z71ubgUwz5f8&hl=en_US",
   "displayLink": "www.google.com",
   "snippet": "Correctional Centres in British Columbia",
   "htmlSnippet": "Correctional Centres in British Columbia",
   "mime": "image/",
   "image": {
    "contextLink": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=1Xiubw4z5fACCpd5z71ubgUwz5f8&hl=en_US",
    "height": 520,
    "width": 504,
    "byteSize": 62990,
    "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTR0gMZSVrF7H2n1JcfXxbZ25ZgOsc7iW2hsYltXGAYP5bwukZCfcNXyKQ",
    "thumbnailHeight": 131,
    "thumbnailWidth": 127
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have your search engine customized correctly.

Update your [search engine](https://cse.google.com/all) and make sure you have `image search` enabled

---

[image: google]

---

You also want to make sure you have at least one site added in sites to search *(below I added google.com)*

---

[image: google]

---

then you get a response like this

```
{
    "kind": "customsearch#search",
    "url": {
        "type": "application/json",
        "template": ""
    },
    "queries": {
        "request": [
            {
                "title": "Google Custom Search - city",
                "totalResults": "297000000",
                "searchTerms": "city",
                "count": 10,
                "startIndex": 1,
                "inputEncoding": "utf8",
                "outputEncoding": "utf8",
                "safe": "off",
                "cx": "000938323173939893608:mrtwb_hl8cu"
            }
        ],
        "nextPage": [
            {
                "title": "Google Custom Search - city",
                "totalResults": "297000000",
                "searchTerms": "city",
                "count": 10,
                "startIndex": 11,
                "inputEncoding": "utf8",
                "outputEncoding": "utf8",
                "safe": "off",
                "cx": "000938323173939893608:mrtwb_hl8cu"
            }
        ]
    },
    "context": {
        "title": "Google"
    },
    "searchInformation": {
        "searchTime": 0.400265,
        "formattedSearchTime": "0.40",
        "totalResults": "297000000",
        "formattedTotalResults": "297,000,000"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "customsearch#result",
            "title": "Yarra City Council Boundary",
            "htmlTitle": "Yarra <b>City</b> Council Boundary",
            "link": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=1X8_ONIG08PtjQ--SOiAD9Xk8mM8&hl=en",
            "displayLink": "www.google.com",
            "snippet": "Yarra City Council Boundary.",
            "htmlSnippet": "Yarra <b>City</b> Council Boundary.",
            "cacheId": "V02kFnMgkfgJ",
            "formattedUrl": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=1X8...hl=en",
            "htmlFormattedUrl": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=1X8...hl=en",
            "pagemap": {
                "cse_thumbnail": [
                    {
                        "width": "221",
                        "height": "228",
                        "src": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQUjeu8rgqsWGc4u_XkQNcBRull03-9xL9KEUehjmnglOC2op3eS9pkmZ4"
                    }
                ],
                "website": [
                    {
                        "name": "Yarra City Council Boundary",
                        "description": "Yarra City Council Boundary",
                        "url": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1X8_ONIG08PtjQ--SOiAD9Xk8mM8&hl=en",
                        "image": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=1X8_ONIG08PtjQ--SOiAD9Xk8mM8&hl=en"
                    }
                ],
                "metatags": [
                    {
                        "viewport": "initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0,width=device-width",
                        "og:type": "website",
                        "og:title": "Yarra City Council Boundary",
                        "og:description": "Yarra City Council Boundary",
                        "og:url": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1X8_ONIG08PtjQ--SOiAD9Xk8mM8&hl=en",
                        "og:image": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=1X8_ONIG08PtjQ--SOiAD9Xk8mM8&hl=en",
                        "twitter:card": "summary_large_image",
                        "twitter:title": "Yarra City Council Boundary",
                        "twitter:description": "Yarra City Council Boundary",
                        "twitter:image:src": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=1X8_ONIG08PtjQ--SOiAD9Xk8mM8&hl=en"
                    }
                ],
                "cse_image": [
                    {
                        "src": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=1X8_ONIG08PtjQ--SOiAD9Xk8mM8&hl=en"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        ...
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

## working code

heres some code that gets images from the `pagemap` object if you look 
in the `imageobject` property you'll get your images.

```js
// angular to show images 
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("image-query", function($scope) {

  $scope.settings = {
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?",
    data: {
      key: "AIzaSyAh7eEvk6WpvUXd7gFP0dZnLJNSfiKJ2Us",
      cx: "000938323173939893608:evp8tltzv_y"
    },
    method: "GET"
  };

  $scope.query = "";
  $scope.images = [];
  $scope.exts = ["jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gif"];

  $scope.updateImages = function() {
    $scope.settings.data.q = $scope.query

    $.ajax($scope.settings).done(function(res) {
      // empty images from last query
      $scope.images = [];
      var results = res.items;
      // image may or may not have imageobject
      results.forEach(i => {
        if (i.pagemap.imageobject) {
          i.pagemap.imageobject.forEach(o => {
            if (o.url && $scope.exts.some(ext => o.url.includes(ext))) {
              $scope.images.push(o.url);
              $scope.$apply();
            }
          })
        }
      });

      // uncomment to see logged images
      // console.dir($scope.images);
    })
  }

});
```

```css
#root {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#image-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#image-gallery li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="root" ng-app="app" ng-controller="image-query">
  <h1>Search Images</h1>
  <input ng-model="query" id="search" placeholder="search an image" />
  <br/>
  <button ng-click="updateImages()">Search</button>
  <hr width="100%" />
  <ul id="image-gallery" height="100%">
    <li ng-repeat="img in images track by $index" ng-model="images">
      <img height="100px" width="100px" src="{{img}}" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I now am getting the response you are getting. I however don't see a URL list of images. How would I get this list of images?

Comment: @Jon there  are images in `items[i]` try checking `items[i].pagemap`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I have updated my answer by posting my JSON response. I don't see `items[i].pagemap` in my response, and I don't see any image URLs in your response either. The only image URLs I do see are ones to Google Map.

Comment: To note, I am trying to get a list of photos back from Google Image which I can use in my application.

Comment: @Jon the image urls are there if you look at the code i added you can find them in `items[i].pagemap.imageobject` there are other images you can use in `items[i].pagemap` it depends on the schema you have.

Comment: Thank you for your example. I noticed that the images returned in your gallery are different then the images returned from when I am performing a Google Image search. For example, performing a search for 'Miami' in your gallery yielded lots of images with an image of a lightbulb while Google Image yielded images of the actual city. I am looking to get a list of photo URLs from the Google Image search.

Comment: Poking around, I'm not sure Google Custom Search is the correct API for me. I played around with their API explorer but I'm skeptical about getting the same image data back as what I would get if I went into Google Image Search. I feel like the data I am getting back from Google Custom Search is somehow being filtered and therefore not performing a global internet-wide search.

Comment: When configuring your Google Search engine, you have the option of selecting to search from the entire web instead of specific domains. Unfortunately, you have a limited amount of calls before you need to pay.